# Installing version 1.15 of tensorflow-serving-api to Centos 8

Tags: tensorflow, centos, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to install Tensorflow-serving to my Centos 8 machine. Installing with Docker image is not an option for Centos. So I try to install with pip. These are the commands for installing tensorflow-model-server:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-serving-api==1.15
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tensorflow-model-server
```

The problem is I need version 1.15.0 and I couldn't find how to modify links to install the 1.15 version. Any help for modifying links, ideas for installing "tensorflow/serving" to Centos 8 will be appreciated by me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the links:

```
wget 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server-1.15.0/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.15.0_all.deb'
dpkg -i tensorflow-model-server_1.15.0_all.deb
pip3 install tensorflow-serving-api==1.15
```

With these commands, it works :)